# How to get the number of dates in a month of a range of two years

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I have to create a procedure which will populte the year its number of days in a month and the name of the month and it will start from  a  given year and will have a end year, i.e for example

```
YEAR  MONTH DAYS
2015  JAN   31
2015  FEB   28
.
.
2015 DEC    30
```

like that .
Please help me how to get this done .I can determine the total number of months and number of days in a year of each year like this

```
declare @y int;
declare @cnt int = 2015;
set @y = 2012;
while @y<@cnt
begin 
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,  cast(@y as char(4)),  cast(@y+1 as char(4)))    Months ,DATEDIFF(DAY,  cast(@y as char(4)),  cast(@y+1 as char(4))) Days ,@y Year
set @y = @y+1;
end;
```

This will give the year , its number of months and number of days in a year.But i can not populate this please help

Comment: You should use a tally table here instead of a loop. But what is this for? Is it homework?

Comment: @SeanLange no i need this in my project can you help ? please

Comment: Well the number of days in each month are always the same except for February so aside from February this is kind of pointless to do in a query.

Comment: @SeanLange  agreed  but i need this , can you help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only month you really need to worry about is February. Most years that divide equally by 4 are a leap year ([there are some exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)).

This query hard codes the months.  To generate a list of years I've used [recursion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions), as this can be copied/pasted.  However, there are better ways to do this, including [tally tables](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/) and [calendar tables](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/30/calendar-tables-in-t-sql/), both of which I highly recommend.

```
DECLARE @StartYear INT = 2000;
DECLARE @EndYear INT = 2020;

WITH 
    Years AS
    (
            SELECT
                @StartYear AS Year

        UNION ALL

            SELECT 
                Year + 1
            FROM
                Years
            WHERE
                Year < @EndYear
    )
SELECT
    y.Year,
    DaysInMonth.Month,
    CASE
        -- Feb logic based on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm
        WHEN DaysInMonth.Month = 'Feb' THEN
            CASE 
                WHEN y.Year % 4 = 0 AND y.Year % 100 = 0 AND y.Year % 400 = 0 THEN 29
                WHEN y.Year % 4 = 0 AND y.Year % 100 <> 0 THEN 29
                ELSE 28
            END                
        ELSE DaysInMonth.Days
    END
FROM
    (
        VALUES
            ('Jan', 31),
            ('Feb', 28),
            ('Mar', 31),
            ('Apr', 30),
            ('May', 31),
            ('Jun', 30),
            ('Jul', 31),
            ('Aug', 31),
            ('Sep', 30),
            ('Oct', 31),
            ('Nov', 30),
            ('Dec', 31)
    ) AS DaysInMonth (Month, Days)

    CROSS JOIN Years AS y
;
```

To wrap this inside a [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourSchema.YourProcedureName
(
    @StartYear INT,
    @EndYear INT
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH
        Years AS
    ...
    CROSS JOIN Years AS y
GO
```

Comment: Updated.  Remove the two declare statements and place the remaining query inside the procedure template.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using `master.dbo.spt_values` as tally table

```
declare @start int = 2000
declare @end int = 2015

select
    [year]
    , [month] = choose(n, 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN'
                        , 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC')
    , [days] = choose(n, 31, iif([year] % 400 = 0 or ([year] % 100 <>0 and [year] % 4 = 0), 29, 28)
                        , 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31)
from
    master.dbo.spt_values
    cross apply (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) v(n)
    cross apply (select [year] = number + @start) q
where
    type = 'P'
    and number < @end - @start
```

Comment: can you write a procedure which will take two paramers ?